# What certificates are trusted in truststore?

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, truststore

I do not know very well keystore / truststore lingo but as far as I'm concerned, a truststore keeps the certificates trusted by a peer server.

I can view the content of a keystore using

```
keytool -list -keystore refArchive/testkeystore
Enter keystore password: password
```

Is there any equivalent for the truststore? How can I view the trusted certificates?

thx!

Comment: For a truststore with just certificates, you don't actually need to enter a password either. You can just press enter when prompted for a password, and the certificates are still displayed.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Is there any equivalent for the truststore? How can I view the trusted
>   certificates?

Yes there is.The exact same command since keystore and truststore differ *only* in what they store i.e. private key or signed public key (certificate)

No other difference

Answer (score 80):

Trust store generally (actually should only contain **root** CAs but this rule is violated in general) contains the certificates that of the [root CAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962065.aspx) (public CAs or private CAs). You can verify the list of certs in trust store using

```
keytool -list -v -keystore truststore.jks
```

Comment: You can also set the password as the `-storepass <your_password>` argument, and not type it manually.